# Makefile wildcard and variable expansion

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile (abbreviated):

```
COMPILE                  = armcc
LINK                     = armlink
SRCDIR := ./src1 \
          ./src2

INCLUDES := -I ./inc 
CSRC := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
# CSRC := ./src1/*.c ./src2/*.c
OBJS := $(CSRC:.c=.o)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @echo "Clean Finished"

%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling $<
    @$(COMPILE) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

mktest: $(OBJS) Makefile
    @echo $(CSRC)
    @echo $(OBJS)
    @echo building mktest
    @$(LINK) -o mktest.axf
```

When I run it the wildcard only expanded for the last entry in the SRCDIR variable, which is ./src2. The output shown below.

```
c:> make mktest
./src1 ./src2/file2.c
./src1 ./src2/file2.o
building mktest
```

If I replace the line where CSRC defined, with the line below it. It works fine, and the output shown below.

```
c:> make mktest
./src1/*.c ./src2/*.c
./src1/*.o ./src2/*.o
building mktest
```

This is OK if I only have a few sub-directories I want to include. But if I want to include more, the Makefile will become ugly. Am I not using the wildcard function properly here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you would need your `CSRC` definition to be is:

```
CSRC:= $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIR),$(wildcard $(dir)/*))
```

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function):

> `$(wildcard pattern…)`
>
> This string, used anywhere in a makefile, is replaced by a space-separated list of names of existing files that match one of the given file name patterns…

This means your original line actually reads as:

```
CSRC := $(wildcard src1/ src2/*.c)
```

That is files whose names are matching against `src1/` or `src2/*.c`.